# How can I make "RESULT" represent the previous result (double variable) in a simple java calculator program?

Tags: java, type-conversion, calculator

I'm writing a simple calculator program that takes in two operands and does an selected operation. I would like for the user to able to enter "RESULT" as one of the operands, which would represent the previous result. How can I go about making "RESULT" equal to the previous result? The method where the operands are entered is below.

```
  public static double[] enterOperands()  { // This method prompts the user to enter 2 operands.
    System.out.print("Enter first operand: ");
    double operand1 = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter second operand: ");
    double operand2 = scanner.nextDouble();

    return new double[]{operand1, operand2}; // The operands are stored as an array.
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried & the general structure/outline of your current code.

Comment: You should post a minimal sample code of what you're trying to accomplish. That's the easiest way we can help you.

Comment: Should I add the entire thing? It's 125 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last answer in a **double variable** & **print** the variable when **RESULT** is entered.

```
    String operand = scanner.next();
    if (operand.equals("RESULT") {
    System.out.print(YOUR_STORED_VARIABLE) }
```

*if this do not solve your issue , please try to give your code snippet & Explain it*

Comment: Haha, I know I need to store the last variable as a double (I already did) but I want to know how to make RESULT represent the double when it is entered.

Comment: for that , you have to take input as String & Equate it to RESULT . then print the stored variable when user enter RESULT.